# Connection timeout in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, connection, connection-timeout

I have an application running in Apache Tomcat, it take 50-55 sec to complete execution. I run the application by `http://localhost:8080/myapp`. It's running for 30 sec and I get `Http Status 403 Evaluation of myapp did not complete within allowed time limit`. I tried change `connectionTimeout="600000"` from `connectionTimeout="20000"` but its not working. also tried change `disableUploadTimeout="false"` but no luck.

any idea?

Note: I know the application is running, I got partial output from the application but not full output.